# Is babel necessary in React Project?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I only installed webpack4 not babel7 in my React project because my react website is only for latest Chrome browser.

But webpack produced an error:

> Module parse failed: Unexpected token (6:2)
>   You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
>   | 
>   | ReactDom.render(
>     ,
>   |   document.getElementById('app')
>   | );

When I installed '@babel/core babel-loader @babel/preset-env @babel/preset-react' and add babel-loader in webpack.config.js, this error disappeared. It worked well.

So, I think babel is necessary to be resolved by webpack. Am I right?

Comment: Babel has different parts to it. JSX is something that browsers don't recoganize. So babel helps to convert the JSX to plain JS. you can ignore other transformations as u planned to.